# Hover Over Text, Image Fades In

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just beginning to learn Javascript and Jquery but I've been having a lot of issues lately. I've found similar topics but nothing that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Essentially, I want to hover over a text link, and have an image fade in on a different place of the page. I'm not sure if this can be done with CSS, because I am not familiar with newer CSS codes unfortunately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can post `html` , `css` , `js` ?

Comment: **Ya** it could be done in CSS only, if that helps...

Comment: You will be more likely to get code if you show that you've at least tried something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css only, could do animations, fades, transforms on it etc....####EDIT added fade in

```css
img{opacity:0;}
a:hover +img{-webkit-animation:changeOpacity 5s;animation:changeOpacity 5s;}
@-webkit-keyframes changeOpacity {
    0%   {opacity:0;}    
    100% {opacity:1;}
 }

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes changeOpacity {
  0%   {opacity:0;}    
    100% {opacity:1;}
 }
```

```html
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1">Hover the see Full image,click to go there</a>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1" width="200" height="200" />
<br>
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1">Hover the see Full image,click to go there</a>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1" width="200" height="200" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is it possible to have it slowly fade out when your mouse goes off the link as well?

Comment: not sure, off the top of my head the only thing I can think of is that if you put an invisible elem around the a that can be hovered maybe but I don't , give me a minute, if I can't get something then might need js for that bit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a#hoverme').hover(function(){
    $( "#book" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        console.log('done!');
      });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' id='hoverme'>link</a>
<br>
<img id="book" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TODEi.png" style='display:none;'>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the image fade out when you release your mouse from the link?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple with a:hover and display:none/block.

CSS:

```
    .hover_img a { 
         position: relative; 
    }

    .hover_img a span { 
         position: absolute; 
         display: none; 

    }

    .hover_img a:hover span { 
         display: block; 
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hover_img">
     <a href="#">Show Image<span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-3.jpg" /></span></a>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwObyo

Answer (score 0):

make the **image a child element of the a tag**, otherwise you cannot hover with css. than set the position from the image as you wish.

```
img{
    position: absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover image{
    opacity:1;
}
```

if it is not possible to make the image a child of the a tag than you have to use jquery.

```
$('a').mouseenter(function(){
    $('img').addClass('opacity')
});
$('a').mouseleave(function(){
    $('img').removeClass('opacity')
});
```

css should stay the same except for

```
 a:hover image{
    opacity:1;
}
```

you make:

```
.opacity{
    opacity:1;
}
```

greetings timotheus

Comment: downvoted, mine isn't a child of the <a> tag and it works, as long as it comes after the a that triggers it most of the time you can get it with pure css

Comment: didn't know that the next sibling also works.. thanks for this.

Comment: This is a much better answer than @Billy - you just need to change the CSS selector to `a:hover +img` to make it work.